# Internet Explorer reports differing versions in USER_AGENT and in info dialog

Tags: http, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, user-agent

I am checking Browser version using php. I am getting version 8.
When I am checking it using setting of IE, I am getting it version 10. The code is as follow:

```
   <?php
       echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n"; 
   ?>
```

Comment: Do you have compatibility mode on?

Comment: no,No compatibility mode is not on

Comment: If the string in `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` actually is `Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows [...]; Trident/6.0)` (note the Trident/6.0) then _it is_ IE's compatibility mode.

Comment: When determining the version of Internet Explorer, you should first look for Trident/4.0 (IE8), Trident/5.0 (IE9), Trident/6.0 (IE10), Trident/7.0 (IE11). Only if these are not present, you should look at MSIE X.

Comment: Bear in mind IE will activate compatibility mode without your knowledge if you have got issues with your doctype or encoding.